# How to set a double format by locale

Tags: java, locale, number-formatting, decimalformat

I those input strings:

```
 10000,20
 4000,10
 5,400.20
```

I am trying to format them with locale:

```
nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
double newLoc = nf.parse(split[5]).doubleValue();
```

And also like this:

```
   nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    double newLoc = nf.parse(split[5]).doubleValue();
```

Result is:
 for Locale.FRANCE

```
5400.2 
4000.0 
10000.0
```

For Locale.ENGLISH

```
4000.0
10000.0
5400.0
```

But what in need is smth like this:
for Locale.France

```
10 000,2 
4 000,1
5 400,2
```

And Locale.English

```
10,000.2
4,000.1
5,400.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't present double or float in format `10,000.2` or `10 000,2`, this is String format. You can use for example `String.format()` method to do it. More info about this read [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/).